How to bridge 2 SSIDs to share LAN resources
I have a Huawei router which allows me to create 2 SSIDs (the main one and the other for guests), the problem is that it is impossible to share LAN resources despite that they share same IP range and gateway. How can I make the 2 communicate.
The option I only explored, is to created a third access point (virtual) and then connect all devices using that (since I am trying to avoid either of the 2 primary SSIDs for personal reasons). I believe there must be a way to make these 2 communicate?

The purpose of having a "guest" network is isolation, the very thing you're trying to defeat? It makes no sense.

“I believe there must be a way to make these 2 communicate?” - With different hardware, it would be possible, but the guest network function of your hardware it’s not possible

@ChanganAuto Ok but I was thinking to use only LAN on guest without internet. like I want to share files not internet since I can always create a 3rd AP without internet for both but ideally wanted to use only internet on primary AP but not guest. Don't know if it makes sense now.

With better routers, this would be possible.  If you can not see any appropriate configuration settings for guest mode then your router does not support what you want.  It is probably defaulting to isolation.  You could buy another router.
Also be aware that any mobile connecting to a Wifi network that has no internet connection means that it will have no data (by default).  That is mobile data would be ignored.  Particular mobiles may have settings to override this.
